# How to compute map output size in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have written a mapreduce program that has 30,000 map output record.the output record consists of key:intwitable and value:intwritable that means each record is 8 Byte and the output size is 3000*8=240 KByte. but in browser the "map output" is about 490KByte.
What's its reason? How do i must calculate the size of map output?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have map output compression set?

Comment: 3000*8=240 KByte? How?

Comment: The detail of a mapreduce job has a Counter: `Map output bytes`. You can check it in your browser.

Comment: @JtheRocker execuse me, I have 30000 output record and the size of each record is 8 byte(two intwritables).

Comment: @zsxwing have said above that this parametr is 490KByte but when i calculate, it is 240KByte.

Comment: @user1878364, so -> 30000 *(key=8bytes + delimiter + value=8bytes) ~ 490KByte per record? Can this be the case? Please reply. Thanks!

Comment: @JtheRocker my key is intwritable and my value is intwritable too.so the size of each map output record becomes 4+4=8(key+value).Do i need to calculate delimiter size in the map output record?Thanks.

Comment: @user1878364, I know I have messed up a little. I have deleted my answer, Can you tell me what outputformat you are using and also some dummy data you are writing to HDFS? e.g. - IntWritable iw = new IntWritable(); iw.set(what?)?